# Android ошибка открытия сайта на эмуляторе WebView

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

На WebView не открывается сайт на эмуляторе Android 6.0, 5.0.

Через Chrome Inspect в браузере, отображает

```
ReferenceError
message: "Promise is not defined"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
 deliveryFormByStep.js:5
TypeError
message: "Cannot read property 'comment' of null"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
 deliveryFormByStep.js:5
TypeError
 deliveryFormByStep.js:5
TypeError
message: "Object [object Array] has no method 'find'"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
 deliveryFormByStep.js:5
TypeError
message: "Object [object Array] has no method 'find'"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
 deliveryFormByStep.js:5
TypeError
message: "Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'from'"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
 deliveryFormByStep.js:5
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null newHeader.js:1
```

На обычном телефоне вроде работает на Android 6.0, но мне нужно дебажить на эмуляторе, так как старого устройства нет.

Есть варианты решения?

Используемые настройки:

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
webView.settings.databaseEnabled = true
webView.settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
```

**Log:**

```
05-13 08:33:28.782 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki D/myWEB: ReferenceError: Promise is not defined -- From line 5 of https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js
05-13 08:33:28.782 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "ReferenceError: Promise is not defined", source: https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js (5)
05-13 08:33:28.842 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki D/myWEB: TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of null -- From line 5 of https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js
05-13 08:33:28.842 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of null", source: https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js (5)
05-13 08:33:28.852 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki D/myWEB: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dots' of null -- From line 5 of https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js
05-13 08:33:28.852 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dots' of null", source: https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js (5)
05-13 08:33:28.862 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki D/myWEB: TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'find' -- From line 5 of https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js
05-13 08:33:28.862 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'find'", source: https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js (5)
05-13 08:33:28.872 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki D/myWEB: TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'find' -- From line 5 of https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js
05-13 08:33:28.872 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'find'", source: https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js (5)
05-13 08:33:28.882 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki D/myWEB: TypeError: Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'from' -- From line 5 of https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js
05-13 08:33:28.882 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "TypeError: Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'from'", source: https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/6f338872/deliveryFormByStep.js (5)
05-13 08:33:28.922 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki D/myWEB: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null -- From line 1 of https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/d253c1f6/newHeader.js
05-13 08:33:28.922 8239-8239/com.app.peshkariki I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null", source: https://3.peshkariki.ru/assets/d253c1f6/newHeader.js (1)
```

Код, 5 строчка

```
if(installedModules[moduleId])
{
    return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
}
```

Comment: ошибка вроде как в js, вы к сайту доступ имеете?

Comment: @Anrew да, проблема только в эмуляторах на старых версиях Android, на эмуляторе Android 8.1, например таких нет

Comment: попробуйте добавить логгирование в webview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859970/how-can-i-see-javascript-errors-in-webview-in-an-android-app чтобы увидеть в чем проблема

Comment: @Andrew добавил ниже

Comment: а можете показать фрагмент кода `deliveryFormByStep.js` файла включающий 5 строку?

Comment: @Andrew Добавил, это 5 строчка

Comment: нашел вот два варианта https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490328/gulp-autoprefixer-throwing-referenceerror-promise-is-not-defined и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716083/referenceerror-promise-is-not-defined может что-то поможет) и я думаю нужно добавить метку `js` в вопрос чтобы знающие люди смогли его увидеть и возможно помочь